# How do I create a new website in IIS for asp.net core application with all the necessary settings?

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis, asp.net-core

How do I create a new website in IIS for asp.net core application with all the necessary settings?
Assumes IIS asp.net core module is already installed. Also assumed application is already deployed to iis folder location.

Comment: Its a same way as you create website in IIS , create new website and publish your code to that website folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module "WebAdministration"

# Create app pool
$appName = "Test.WebUI"

New-Item IIS:\AppPools\$appName
Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\${appName}" -name "managedRuntimeVersion" -value ""
Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\${appName}" -name "autoStart" -value $true
Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\${appName}" -name "startMode" -value "AlwaysRunning"

# "ApplicationPoolIdentity" = best
# "LocalSysten" = bad idea!
# "NetworkService" = not so bad
# "SpecificUser" = useful if the user needs special rights. See other examples
# below for how to do this.
Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\${appName}" -name "processModel" -value @{identitytype="ApplicationPoolIdentity"}

$webSitePath = 'C:\inetpub\' + $appName
$port = 58807

# Create new website
New-Item IIS:\Sites\$appName -physicalPath $webSitePath  -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":${port}:"}
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$appName -name applicationPool -value $appName
```

Thanks to https://octopus.com/blog/iis-powershell